# Firebase Write Access for Signed Url not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, signed-url

I have a cloud function which will generate signed url for the uploaded file into the firebase storage and was able to generate the signed url:

```
const result = await Promise.all([
  storageRef.getSignedUrl({
   action: "read",
   expires
 }),
 storageRef.getSignedUrl({
  action: "write",
  expires
  })
]);
```

And when I tried to access the file with write access from that url via browser, below is the error message i was getting:

```
<Error>
<script/>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Details>
<StringToSign>GET 1709282976 /mystorage.appspot.com/files/-NrBwOCgu226c7DtrgPh/7zEiXfTaen25qDzIpuy4.pdf</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

The read access link/token works fine, but the write access toekn does not. Is there a way to:

1. Solve this write access token
2. Create a signed url with read AND Write access in one token?

My firebase storage rules are already public so I dont know what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, Firebase security rules have no effect on signed URLs.  A signed URL is a GCP concept only and Firebase does not apply.

> Solve this write access token

I don't see that there's anything wrong with the URL using for writing.  If you load it into a browser, that will be a read action, not a write action.  I would not expect a URL creating for writing would work for reading.

> Create a signed url with read AND Write access in one token?

There is nothing in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#should-you-use) that suggests a single signed URL can be used for multiple types of actions.  You must choose which [action](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/storage/getsignedurlconfig#_google_cloud_storage_GetSignedUrlConfig_action_member) to allow for that URL: "read", "write", "delete", or "resumable".  So, if you want to perform multiple actions, you will need a URL for each action.

Comment: Interesting question. I tried doing something similar a while back but kept getting a 403 error. I assume this can only be solved from the GCP console @DougStvenson ?